# How to include custom constraints/rankings on a RANSAC plane estimator?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, robotics, ransac

I'm trying to segment a plane from a point cloud using the Point Cloud library and I have some prior information about the plane model (i.e, the normal should be similar to the z axis and the height (d) should be around 0).

Is there a way I can force the RANSAC algorithm to prefer coefficients similar to my prior model? I think this might be possible either by including constraints on the model or modifying the rankings of the selected planes.

I tried to filter the data with a PassThrough filter that only keeps points which are around the prior plane. Then I used a SACSegmentation object to find a plane on the filtered data with a normal-plane model and a tolerance on the normal angle.

I tried using the parallel plane model as well.

```cpp
  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr indices_for_segmentation(new pcl::PointIndices);
  pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZL> pass_through;
  pass_through.setInputCloud(cloud_);
  pass_through.setIndices(clean_indices);
  pass_through.setFilterFieldName("z");
  pass_through.setFilterLimits(z_min_lim, z_max_lim);
  pass_through.filter(indices_for_segmentation->indices);


  pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers(new pcl::PointIndices);
  pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZL> ransac;
  ransac.setOptimizeCoefficients(true);
  ransac.setIndices(indices_for_segmentation);
  ransac.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_PERPENDICULAR_PLANE);
  ransac.setMethodType(pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
  ransac.setDistanceThreshold(plane_thresh);
  ransac.setInputCloud(cloud_);
  ransac.setAxis(Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 1));  // search around the z axis
  ransac.setEpsAngle(pcl::deg2rad(5));
  ransac.segment(*inliers, *coefficients_);
```

The problems with the current solution is that

- in both cases (parallel and normal planes) the algorithm doesn't seem to use the epsAngle constraint rigidly (it seems to be used as somewhat of a recommendation)
- this doesn't take care of the requirement for the height of the plane.
- the pass through filter sometimes leaves just a few points and that makes the plane estimation unstable (a different plane is estimated in every frame)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me, that you have some misunderstandings regarding how to use `PCL`.

You are declaring the RANSAC estimator with `pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZL>`.

If you only provide `XYZ` data, how do you think RANSAC is going to compute the angular difference between the point's normal and the surface normal? Correct, it **cannot**.

So first of all, you have to compute normals for your input cloud. See this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php) for more information.

Once you have the normals, you just have to do minor changes to the existing code.

```
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers(new pcl::PointIndices);

pcl::SACSegmentationFromNormals<pcl::PointXYZL, pcl::Normal> ransac; // ** change to SACSegmentationFromNormals
ransac.setOptimizeCoefficients(true);
ransac.setIndices(indices_for_segmentation);
ransac.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_NORMAL_PLANE);
ransac.setMethodType(pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
ransac.setDistanceThreshold(plane_thresh);
ransac.setInputCloud(cloud_);
ransac.setInputNormals(normals_); // ** set input normals
ransac.setAxis(Eigen::Vector3f(0, 0, 1));  // search around the z axis
ransac.setEpsAngle(pcl::deg2rad(5));
ransac.segment(*inliers, *coefficients_);
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: I corrected my question, I actually used SACMODEL_PERPENDICULAR_PLANE which compare the normal of the computed plane and checks if it's within `epsAngle` from the given (prior) axis used in `setAxis`